# Password not required

Tags: 12.10, password, suspend, hibernate

I have a password set on my laptop running 12.10 smoothly, but the password requirement on boot from suspend or hibernation has vanished. It is still required for sudoing or boot from full shutdown. How can I get my password back?

Require password on wake is enabled, so that's not the problem. Also, in lightdm.conf there is no line saying autologin-user=. I can't exactly comment out a blank line.

Suspend/hibernate is enabled from the regular menu and both function correctly.

Comment: How do you invoke suspend/hibernate? Using the regular menu?

Comment: Considering those settings are all alright, I would guess that this might be an instance of the following bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1083030

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Settings > Brightness & Lock. There you can tick "Require my password when waking up from suspend".

[image]

Comment: @AlexMundy Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please include all new information in your question by *editing* it. And that should have been in your question from the beginning in the first place. This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, you see. :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the terminal and type in:

```
sudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

And find the line saying

```
autologin-user=
```

Replace it with

```
#autologin-user=
```